# array_combine usage or query error?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have never used array_combine before and I am getting a "Boolean instead of resource" error in the query.  If I change the query to read ... WHERE cal_id = " . $quidx . "; the Boolean error goes away but I get unexpected T_STRING errors later in the script for reasons I can't figure, and the outcome of the query is nothing.

Main question: Is this the proper usage for array_combine?   If so, what am I missing in the rest of this script that causes no information after the query?  $quid1 is an array of id numbers and $tm is an array of Unix timestamps.  Both arrays check out to have the same number of rows consistently.  After array_combine, $cls1 returns a valid array of both previous arrays but they don't seem to work in the query.

Thanks for helping. I'm still learning.

I have edited the script to include the new query statement.  Problems now are with the foreach statements where the error reads invalid argument.

```
$cls1 = array_combine($quid1, $tm);
      $quidx = array_values($quid1);
      $quclx = array_values($tm);
//// note to self.. start final query for email write with new id data, likely redundant.
$qumail = "SELECT cal_id, cal_name, cal_time, cal_description FROM webcal_entry WHERE cal_id in (" . implode (',' , $quidx) . ")";
$wemail = mysql_query($qumail);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($wemail, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $quname2 = $row[1];
    $qtime = $row[2]
    $qudesc2 = $row[3];
```

Here's the complete script section where this is applicable.  I'm still pecking through it so it's not all fixed yet:

```
$cls1 = array_combine($quid1, $tm);
      $quidx = array_values($quid1);
      $quclx = array_values($tm);
//// note to self.. start final query for email write with new id data, likely redundant.
$qumail = "SELECT cal_id, cal_name, cal_time, cal_description FROM webcal_entry WHERE cal_id in (" . implode (',' , $quidx) . ")";
$wemail = mysql_query($qumail);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($wemail, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $quname2 = $row[1];
    $qtime = $row[2]
    $qudesc2 = $row[3];
}
    foreach ($qtime as $key=>$btUx) {
        if (strlen($btUx) < 6){
        $btUx = '0' . $btUx;
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
        $unixEpoch = strtotime($btUx);
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
        $formtime = date("H:i", $unixEpoch);
      }
    }
    foreach ($tm as $key=>$tf) {
        $idnotime = 0;
        $idnow = (strlen($tf) > 2);

    switch($tf) {
      case $idnow:
        $repmlnow = sprintf("Event: %s \nTime: %s \nDesc: %s \n\n", $row[1], $formtime, $row[3]);
        break;
      case $idnotime:
        $repmlnotm = sprintf("Event: %s \nDesc: %s \n\n", $row[1], $row[3]);
        break;
   }
}   
/////===================== send mail...
```

This is my last edit unless there are other comments.  I have changed the original script to the following and everything seems to work properly in this case thanks to the contributor below...

```
$cls1 = array_combine($quid1, $tm);
      $quidx = array_values($quid1);
      $quclx = array_values($tm);
$qumail = "SELECT cal_id, cal_name, cal_time, cal_description FROM webcal_entry WHERE cal_id in (" . implode (',' , $quidx) . ")";
$wemail = mysql_query($qumail);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($wemail, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $quname2 = $row[1];
    $qtime = $row[2];
    $qudesc2 = $row[3];
}
if(strlen($qtime) < 6){
    $btUx = '0' . $qtime;
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $unixEpoch = strtotime($btUx);
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
    $formtime = date("H:i", $unixEpoch);
}elseif(strlen($qtime) > 5){
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $unixEpoch = strtotime($value);
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
    $formtime = date("H:i", $unixEpoch);
}
foreach ($quclx as $key=>$tf) {
    $idnotime = 0;
    $idnow = (strlen($tf) > 2);

    switch($tf) {
      case $idnow:
        $repmlnow = sprintf("Event: %s \nTime: %s \nDesc: %s \n\n", $quname2, $formtime, $qudesc2);
        break;
      case $idnotime:
        $repmlnotm = sprintf("Event: %s \nDesc: %s \n\n", $quname2, $qudesc2);
        break;
  }
}   
/////===================== send mail...
```

Comment: Thanks habibillah, this is definitely getting somewhere but it's not quite the gold ring.  I am getting some data coming through and this may have resolved the query issue, but now there are errors at the foreach statements.  I will make a couple of edits to the script above and search for more help from there.  Thanks again!

Comment: I'll also read up on the implode statement.  That's new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$quidx is an array with numerical index as key and $quid1 array values as it value. try change query become:

```
$qumail = "SELECT cal_id, cal_name, cal_time, cal_description FROM webcal_entry WHERE cal_id in (" . implode (',' , $quidx) . ")";
```